# Uislider in a tableView Cell

Tags: objective-c

hi everyone i'm new in iOS programming ! I have a custom table view controller with custom table view cell ! one of those cell have a uislider and a label ! I want to change label text when slider change value ! this is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



NSDictionary *cellInfo = [[self.sections objectAtIndex:currentTab] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
HLNotificheCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[cellInfo objectForKey:@"cell"] forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *radioIndicator = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];

radioIndicator.image = (currentBullet != indexPath.row) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioOff"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioOn"];

UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
av.opaque = NO;
av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewsSeparetor.png"];
cell.backgroundView = av;


cell.slider.maximumValue = 100;
cell.slider.minimumValue = 1;
cell.slider.continuous = TRUE;
//set a method which will get called when a slider in a cell changes value
[cell.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//Keep a reference to each slider by assigning a tag so that we can determine
//which slider is being changed
cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row;

//Grab the value from the sliderValuesArray and set the slider knob to that position






return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender{
HLNotificheCell *cell = [[HLNotificheCell alloc]init];
if (sender == cell.slider) {
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f", cell.slider.value];
}
```

}

Comment: the problem is that when i run the app crash and say '-[UITableViewCell slider]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Have you connected the slider to the custom cell?. Clean project and build again. I also faced the same issue yesterday.

Comment: Did you register cell class for this table view? Like 
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: ? Anyway you should use one reuse identifier across one cell type instead of doing this: [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cell"] (which actually depends on indexPath.row)

Comment: Yes I hav registered the cell class ! do you think that the problem is resue identifier? I have use object for key because I put the cell and their content with ns  dictionary !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is **a lot** of bad practices in your code. Please let me explain.

Let's begin with your `HLNotificheCell` class. I think header file should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define HLNotificheCellIdentifier @"HLNotificheCellIdentifier"

@interface HLNotificheCell : UITableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISlider *slider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *radioIndicator;

@end
```

and implementation file:

```
#import "HLNotificheCell.h"

@implementation HLNotificheCell

- (instancetype)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
        _slider.maximumValue = 100;
        _slider.minimumValue = 1;
        _slider.continuous = YES; //YES is more natural in objc rather than TRUE.
        [self addSubview: _slider];

        _radioIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [self addSubview:_radioIndicator];

        UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
        av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        av.opaque = NO;
        av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewsSeparetor.png"];
        self.backgroundView = av;

        //it's better to use built-in textLabel instead of creating your own. Trust me when you will have 20 different customized cells you will get lost with their names.
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // layout your self.slider and self.radioIndicator here or use xib for it.
    // e.g. this will layout slider to fit whole cell:
    self.slider.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

Ok, lets go now to cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // try to dequeue cell if exist
    HLNotificheCell *cell = (HLNotificheCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HLNotificheCellIdentifier];

    // if doesn't, create new one.
    if (!cell) { // is enough to set slider target only once when cell is created. When reuse is not needed.
        cell = [[HLNotificheCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:HLNotificheCellIdentifier];
        [cell.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }

    //set image as you wish:
    cell.radioIndicator.image = (currentBullet != indexPath.row) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioOff"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioOn"];

    //Keep a reference to each slider by assigning a tag so that we can determine
    //which slider is being changed
    cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row;

     //Grab the value from the sliderValuesArray and set the slider knob to that position

    NSNumber *sliderValue = sliderValuesArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell.slider setValue:sliderValue.floatValue animated:NO]

    return cell;
}
```

and `sliderChanged:` method:

```
-(void)sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender{
    // You cannot do this:
    // HLNotificheCell *cell = [[HLNotificheCell alloc]init];
    // because you have to restore reference from sender.tag as you wrote in cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

    HLNotificheCell *cell = (HLNotificheCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:slider.tag inSection:0]] // I assume you have only 1 section
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f", cell.slider.value]; 
    //save new value to the sliderValuesArray
    self.sliderValuesArray[indexPath.row] = @(cell.slider.value);
}
```

Assumptions:

- when you will use this part of code please **do not** use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`
- yours `sliderValuesArray` is kind of `NSMutableArray` class.
- `sliderValuesArray` has been initialized with size same as number of cells, like:

  ```
  self.sliderValuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:<#numberOfCels#>];
  for (int i = 0; i < sliderValuesArray.count; i++) {
      sliderValuesArray[i] = @(0);
  }
  ```
- your table view contains only one type of cells (HLNotificheCell)

There could be some typos and/or lack of semicolons because I wrote it without compiler.

Comment: thanks a lot! unfortunately are still a novice in this field ! Now I will try as you told me , and I'll let you know! thanks again

Comment: @Neru what if i have 3 sections ??

Answer (score 0):

I doing this easier. Apple write that you can use IBActions for static rows. (You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) in `The Technique for Static Row Content`. But I already tested it on iOS 9 with dynamic cells and it's just works :)

> At first - Custom cell with IBAction

```
@interface SliderTableViewCell ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@end

@implementation SliderTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.slider.minimumValue = 1;
    self.slider.maximumValue = 1000;
}

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
    self.sliderValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1_%.f", self.slider.value];
}
@end
```

> Second - TableView Delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SliderTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kReuseIdentifierSliderCell];
    cell.slider.value = 142;
    cell.sliderValueLabel.text = @"1_142";
        return cell;
}
```

> Third - Run your app and enjoy yourself ;)