# Why are multple UISliders moving at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view where I am display an array of items. Each item has a label and a slider. There are multiple sections, each section has a few sliders. When I drag one slider, a slider 6 positions down moves to the same location and the one another 6 positions after that does so as well, repeating until there are no more sliders. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Class for the table cell

```
 class CharItemCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var charItemLabel: UILabel!

     @IBOutlet weak var charItemSlider: UISlider!
     var charItemId = Int()
     func configureForCharItem(charItem: CharItem) {
         charItemLabel.text = charItem.title
         charItemId = charItem.id
         charItemSlider.tag = charItem.id        
     }

}
```

Table set up code

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return charSections.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return charSections[section].title
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return charSections[section].charItems.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableView.CellIdentifiers.CharItemCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CharItemCell
    cell.configureForCharItem(charSections[indexPath.section].charItems[indexPath.row])
    let myBackView=UIView(frame:cell.frame)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView
    cell.tag = cell.charItemId


    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, tableView.frame.height)) //set these values as necessary

    returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x253850, alpha: 1)
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, tableView.frame.width, 28))
    label.text = charSections[section].title
    label.textColor = UIColorFromHex(0xe8e8e8, alpha: 1)
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 14)
    returnedView.addSubview(label)

    return returnedView
}
```

Example data

```
class CharSection {
    let title: String
    let charItems: Array<CharItem>
    init(title: String, charItems: Array<CharItem>) {
        self.title = title
        self.charItems = charItems
    }
    class func charSections() -> Array<CharSection> {
        return [
            CharSection(title: "QUALITY", charItems: quality()),
            CharSection(title: "LITERATURE/FICTION", charItems: fiction())
        ]
    }
    class func quality() -> Array<CharItem> {
        return [
            CharItem(title: "Overall", value:0.0,id: 1)

        ]
    }
    class func fiction() -> Array<CharItem> {
        return [
            CharItem(title: "Action", value:0.0,id: 2),
            CharItem(title: "Creativity", value:0.0,id: 3)
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: i think you should save slider value in your model classes because when you scroll then cell which is not shown will be removed and another cell wilbe shown,so when you scroll to previous cell that's UISlider should have value previous value.save value on sliderchanged and insert that in cellforrowatindexpath.follow this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448435/uislider-in-a-tableview-cell

Comment: @johnykumar that worked. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: BTW i cannot see where you are assigning value to the slider in code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think you should save slider value in your model classes because when you scroll then cell which is not shown will be removed and another cell wil be shown,
so when you scroll to previous cell that's UISlider should have value previous value.
Save value on sliderChanged and insert that in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
```

follow below link:

[Uislider in a tableView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448435/uislider-in-a-tableview-cell)

Answer (score 1):

Because tableview is reusing the same Cell...

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to reset the slider explicitly

like

```
if sliderValue {
      setSliderValue
}
else {
      resetSlider to inital value
}
```